# PhpStorm SFTP won't write to remote host (AWS EC2)

Tags: save, phpstorm, host

I was able to connect SFTP to my AWS EC2 instance, and I can see all the files and browse through them, open them up in PhpStorm etc..., but when I make a change and save any file in PhpStorm, then refresh the page on my browser the change doesn't show up.

It works if I physically do it in VIM, but PhpStorm SFTP is not writing my changes to the remote host

Is there an extra configuration step I need to do to get it to write to the host as soon as a file changes?

One thing I did notice - If I choose the menu options `Tools | Deployment` the options to upload are greyed out.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer is that the files were under a different ownership.

So I had to go to the root and execute:

```
$ sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user *
```

And that worked.